# Msdropdown opening only with a "slideDown" animation

Tags: jquery, animation, web, slideup, msdropdown

The MsDropDown located at: https://github.com/jgb146/ms-Dropdown/blob/master/msdropdown/js/jquery.dd.js only opening with a "slideDown" animation.

How I can fix that to open with a slideUp animation?

Anyone have a CSS or jQuery tricks?

My example:

```
<div> 
  <html:select property="genericLayoutForm.chart" style="width:300px; height:82px" styleClass="mydds" styleId="chart"> 
  <html:optionsCollection styleClass="mydd" property="genericLayoutForm.charts" /> 
  </html:select> 
</div>
```

Does someone  have a solution for it? Maybe the creator of MsDropDown could create some new parameters to enable users to use, for example: slideUpAnimation or slideDownAnimation.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
var oDropdown = $("#dropdownId").msDropdown(openDirection:alwaysUp ).data("dd");
```